# chkconfig --list does not show newly added service

Tags: linux, service, init.d

I created the service script.

```
etc/init.d/oracle11se
```

The below command succeeds.

```
chkconfig --add oracle11se
```

The below command runs successfully.

```
/etc/init.d/oracle11se start
```

But the command

```
chkconfig --list oracle11se
```

does not show the newly added service. Also the service does not start on reboot.

OS release is redhat 7.2.

Comment: The output from chkconfig reminds you that Red Hat 7 is using systemd.

Comment: it also has backward compatibility.

Comment: Supposedly so.  In practice, not worth talking about.

Answer (score 0):

`systemctl` has replaced `chkconfig`.

This is the command you should use: `systemctl status oracle11se.service`.

If you want to list active services: `systemctl list-units --type service`.